# Comparison between array items

Tags: bash, shell

I've written a script to calculate the bandwidth usage of an OpenVZ container over time and suspend it if it uses too much too quickly. Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Thresholds are in bytes per second
LOGDIR="/var/log/outbound_ddos"
THRESHOLD1=65536
THRESHOLD2=117964

while [ 1 ]
do
        for veid in $(/usr/sbin/vzlist -o veid -H)
        do
                # Create the log file if it doesn't already exist
                if ! test -e $LOGDIR/$veid.log; then
                        touch $LOGDIR/$veid.log
                fi

                # Parse out the inbound/outbound traffic and assign them to the corresponding variables     
                eval $(/usr/sbin/vzctl exec $veid "grep venet0 /proc/net/dev"  |  \
                        awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{printf"CTOUT=%s\n", $9}')

                # Print the output and a timestamp to a log file
                echo $(date +%s) $CTOUT >> $LOGDIR/$veid.log

                # Read last 10 entries into arrays
                i=0
                tail $LOGDIR/$veid.log | while read time byte
                do
                        times[i]=$time
                        bytes[i]=$byte
                        let ++i
                done

                # Time checks & calculations for higher threshold
                counter=0
                for (( i=0; i<9; i++ ))
                do
                        # If we have roughly the right timestamp 
                        if (( times[9-i] < times[8-i] + 20 ))
                                then
                                # If the user has gone over the threshold
                                if (( bytes[9-i] > bytes[8-i] + THRESHOLD2 * 10 ))
                                        then let ++counter
                                fi
                        fi
                done

                # Now check counter
                if (( counter == 9 ))
                        then vzctl stop $veid
                fi

                # Same for lower threshold
                counter=0
                for (( i=0; i<3; i++ ))
                do   
                        # If we have roughly the right timestamp 
                        if (( times[3-i] < times[2-i] + 20 )) 
                                then
                                # If the user has gone over the threshold
                                if (( bytes[3-i] > bytes[2-i] + THRESHOLD1 * 10 ))
                                        then let ++counter
                                fi
                        fi
                done

                # Now check counter
                if (( counter == 2 ))
                        then vzctl stop $veid
                fi
        done
        sleep 10
done
```

I've checked the numbers in /var/log/outbound_ddos/vm101.log and they're increasing by more than the threshold, but nothing is happening.

I added some echo statements to try and figure out where the problem is and it seems to be this comparison that's returning false:

```
if (( bytes[9-i] > bytes[8-i] + THRESHOLD2 * 10 ))
```

So then I tried the following, which printed out nothing:

```
echo ${bytes[9-i]}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  I think the script is nearly done, probably something very simple.

Comment: This script is way too long to expect others to read through the whole thing looking for your bug. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Trouble is, I'm not sure what the problem is really - no errors are reported. The main thing I noticed is that `bytes[i]=$byte` is set and then `echo ${bytes[i]}` returns nothing.

Comment: `while [ 1 ]` doesn't do what you think it does. It happens to loop as you expect, but `while [ 0 ]` would do exactly the same; with 1 argument (0/1) it is true unless the argument is `""`. Use `while true` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell runs the `while read` loop in a subshell (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done) for why it does not work as expected), so your array magic does not propagate outside the `tail | while` construct.

Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) and fix accordingly :-)

Comment: Works a charm. If I could buy you a beer I would.

Comment: I'll come back to that should I ever stop by in Lancaster :-)